# Splitting a string based on the delimiter and moving them under new nodes using XSLT

Tags: xslt

I am using XSLT 1.0. I have the following xml input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <groupLOB>M1 M2 M3 M4</groupLOB>
</root>
```

The tag `<groupLOB>` has the value `M1 M2 M3 M4` Now I want to split the value into multiple strings and store them unde based on the delimiter 'space'i.e. ' '. My end xml should be as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <One>M1</One>
   <Two>M2</Two>
   <Three>M3</Three>
   <Four>M4</Four>
</root>
```

I tried with the following XSLT, but it's not giving me the required output, i.e. I am not sure how to move the split values under the new tags.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:output method="text" />
   <xsl:template match="/*">
      <xsl:value-of select="translate(., ' ', '&#xA;')" />
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Anybody has any idea on how to do that?

Comment: If your processor supports it, you maybe able to use the `tokenize` function in EXSLT. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25855364/exsl-how-to-use-strtokenize. If not, you would have to use a recursive function. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487704/how-to-make-xsl-tokenize-work

Comment: That is only the first problem you have though. You still have the issue of outputing `One`, `Two`, `Three` as the element names, although that should warrant a new question should you not know how to do that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The XSLT 2.0 solution might be:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(groupLOB,' ')">
                <xsl:variable name="elementName">
                    <xsl:number value="position()" format="Ww"/>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:element name="{$elementName}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>                
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And in XSLT 3.0

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0">
    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(groupLOB,' ')">
                <xsl:element name="{format-integer(position(),'Ww')}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>                
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Both output

```
<root>
   <One>M1</One>
   <Two>M2</Two>
   <Three>M3</Three>
   <Four>M4</Four>
</root>
```

Then in XSLT 1.0 you will need to tokenize by the means of an extension function like [EXSLT tokenize()](http://exslt.org/str/functions/tokenize/index.html) or with a recursive template (like Jeni Tennison's [XSLT implementation of EXSLT tokenize](http://exslt.org/str/functions/tokenize/str.tokenize.template.xsl)). The big task is the conversion from numbers to words. Luckly we can see Saxon's open source to translate from a Java implemantation to an XSLT implemantation. This might take time but it is straightforward.

Check the English implementation shipped with Saxon at https://dev.saxonica.com/repos/archive/opensource/trunk/bj/net/sf/saxon/number/Numberer_en.java